# Syncing only first Item of the List

Tags: android, asynchronous

In my program i have to **Sync all** the *List Items* by doing **click on Sync button**, but whenever i do *tap on Sync button*, it is ***syncing only first item*** of the List and whereas, i have to **Sync all the List Item(s)**  available in a List.

```
int position;

 ImageButton buttonSync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    buttonSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startUpload(position);
        }
    });

public void startUpload(final int position) {      

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

     handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    // Show ProgressBar
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Status
    ImageView status = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
    status.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_button);

    new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
    }
    });

    }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageButton buttonSync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    buttonSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=9;i<listview.getchildCount();i++)
             {
            startUpload(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

please use this code and remove listview code from your startUpload() .
i hope that its useful to you..

Comment: hello, facing issue in existing code, see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495199/how-to-sync-whole-list-instead-of-only-visible-records