# How to Sync whole List instead of only visible records

Tags: android, android-listview

Trying to **Sync complete List**, by doing tap on button, but **instead of syncing whole list code only syncing records visible** in a list, my mean when i do scroll down to list, it is not syncing records.

For example, I have **300 records** in a list, but **only 10 records are visible to camera screen** for rest need to scroll, so my program only Syncing those 10 records, not whole list, why ?

```
    ImageButton buttonSync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    buttonSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             for(int i=0; i<lstView.getChildCount(); i++)
             {
                 startUpload(i);
             }          
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show the startUpload() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getChildCount() method returns only the total number of children currently visible in the listview. You will have to get the data to be synced from the data-source (provided to the listview adapter). That is the correct way of doing it.

However, **if you have to sync an item in the listview and update that particular view after syncing it, you can leverage the adapter's [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)**. You can have a flag that is checked to see if that particular record of the listview is to be updated or not.

```
// An array of flags, as many as the number of records in the listview
// such that, flag[0] is set to true to indicate that the first item in the
// listview needs to call startUpload()
private SparseBooleanArray flags = new SparseBooleanArray();

// At onClick, set all the flags to indicate that some data needs to be synced
ImageButton buttonSync = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    buttonSync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             for(int position=0; position<listView.getAdapter().getCount(); position++)
             {
                 flags.put(position, true);
             }

             // Calling this would ensure a call to getView() on every
             // visible child of the listview. That is where we will check if
             // the data is to be synced and displayed or not
             ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

@Override
// In getView of the listview's adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // If this item is to be synced
    if(flags.get(position)) {
        startUpload();

        // Mark as synced
        flags.put(position, false);
    }

    // Rest of the method that draws the view....
}
```

Comment: getting: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter I posted edited code

Comment: Make sure that your adapter is a BaseAdapter and add a cast to that line as ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Hope you understood what my suggestion was. If not, please understand that logic first. Then, include logs & markers to check the flow, instead of having binary "working" & "not working" descriptions. :)

Comment: again i need your help, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731838/how-to-upload-multiple-images-one-by-one  i used your code, but i need a small change, still whenever i am uploading/syncing images, its uploading all at same time, but I want to upload multiple images one by one, like once user do tap on upload all button ...

Comment: bro your help much needed please help once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731838/how-to-upload-multiple-images-one-by-one